CSS flexbox frontend styling properties
Whenever i write align-content to center/flex-end/flex-start without writing flex-wrap, there is no change in the webpage, or the align-content gets ignored but including flex-wrap makes the align-content work. Why so?
I tried to write with and without flex-wrap on all flex-direction values but still the doubt is same.

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example


align-content will have no effect if the is no extra space in the cross direction. So when you use wrap, the flex items get distributed into multiples lines, so that align-content can work.
if you want to align the content of flex-items in the single line, then you can use "align-items:center". This would work.



.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center; /* Align items along the cross axis */
}



